# How can I allow sysops and specific users to hide spam articles in MediaWiki?

Tags: spam, mediawiki

My website is powered by MediaWiki Version  1.29.1.

Sometimes the Recent Changes results page becomes cluttered with spam articles that I wish to hide from the results page. How can I allow specific users to hide them?

Keep in mind, I don't need spam protection and I only need to know how to hide spam articles from the results page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a MediaWiki extension named Extension:Recent_Changes_Cleanup.
This extension does not work with MediaWiki 1.27 and larger.
It only works with 1.23.x - 1.26.x
I search the Official MediaWiki website for MediaWiki Version 1.25.1
I installed the download into a in a sub folder that i named cleanup.
I connected my database to the MediaWiki Version 1.25.1.
I installed the extension and now i can cleanup recent changes page.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Top right side, "More" drop down menu, you can delete the spam pages.

[image]